# How to retrieve data from a list of different data type in haskell

Tags: haskell

How do we retrieve specific data from a list of two different data type? The program only recognizes these chocolate and candy as 1 argument and not as two. Is there another better way of retrieving it?

```
data Store = Store Cookie Sweets [(Chocolate, Candy)]

-- get Candy Chocolate 
getChocolate :: Store -> [(Chocolate, Candy)]
getChocolate (Store _ _ ch) = ch 

-- get Candy Chocolate 
getCandy :: Store -> [(Chocolate, Candy)]
getCandy (Store _ _ ca) = ca
```

Comment: It’s not `data Store = Store Cookie Sweets [(Chocolate, Candy)]`. `Cookie` is a constructor for `Store`, not a type.

Comment: thank you but the way i am retrieving it is wrong or correct?

Comment: It’s wrong, but only because of that misunderstanding as far as validity goes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guessed what you were after was the semantics indicated by the function names, because I don't think your signatures are what you want. You have to remember to finish destructuring your data:

```
data Store = Cookie Sweets [(Chocolate, Candy)]

-- get Candy Chocolate 
getChocolate :: Store -> [Chocolate]
getChocolate (Cookie _ xs) = map fst xs

-- get Candy Chocolate 
getCandy :: Store -> [Candy]
getCandy (Cookie _ xs) = map snd xs
```